# Reverting Xubuntu's startup screen back to Ubuntu's

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, xfce, desktop-environments

I have an Ubuntu installation. I either boot directly into it or use VirtualBox to boot it as a guest on my Windows 10 host. To improve performance, I installed Xfce to use when Ubuntu is a guest.

My first thought was to install `xubuntu-desktop`. Then I decided I did not want the whole Xubuntu environment, so I uninstalled everything (I think) that `xubuntu-desktop` required and just installed `xfce4`.

But, the Xubuntu startup screen is still there.

How can I revert this to the Ubuntu one?

Comment: We don't really know what remnants from the xubuntu desktop are still there.  It's not a great idea to try to switch desktop environments in this way since a DE is comprised of dozens of packages and they can conflict with other existing desktop environments.  That's why Ubuntu comes in several [official flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours), like Xubuntu with the Xfce desktop.  Unfortunately, you will need to pick this apart piece by piece and try to figure out what needs to be changed.  If you want help with this, we will need more details and a better description of the problem(s).

Comment: You can also "Try Ubuntu" from the liveUSB without installing anything so that you don't destroy your existing system out of curiosity to see what another DE is like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did not remove everything `xubuntu-desktop` installed. `plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text` were leftover. So I executed `sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-xubuntu*` and `sudo apt-get purge *xubuntu*` (just in case) and thesesolved my problem.